# Is this a proper way to write a function that returns 9x the value of a register?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Would this work for returning 9 times what's in the RAX register?

```
Times9:
    mov rbp, rax
    add rax, rax  ;(x2)
    add rax, rax  ;(x4)
    add rax, rax  ;(x8)
    add rax, rbp  ;(x9)
    push rax
    ret
```

Comment: Why don't you try it? but why add 3 times when you could do the `x 8` by simply having `shl rax, 3`?

Comment: How can you return if you destroyed the return address by pushing RAX?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it does.  If you are thinking about performance,  you can do this

```
     Times9: 
         mov rbp, rax
         shl rax, 3 // left shift by 3: 8x
         add rax, rbp
         push rax
         ret
```

Comment: Is __push rax ret__ a typo?

Comment: That's certainly decent performance but the functionality problems with pushing rax then returning are likely to swamp it. You can't get any more unoptimised than 'wrong' :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can multiply by 9 in a single instruction using `LEA`:

```
lea rax,[rax + rax*8]   ; rax *= 9
```

Note: I haven't done any benchmarks to see if this is any faster than alternative approaches. It's less code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That's a valid *approach* but your specific implementation has a few problems.

First, it unnecessarily corrupts registers. It's a good rule of thumb to minimise side effects as much as possible such as (in this case) changing `rbp`. Of course, if you specifically *state* that certain registers can be corrupted, you can achieve some more speed by not saving them.

Secondly, `rbp` is not really the correct register for this as it's used in a lot of calling conventions for stack frame management. I'd use one of the other general purpose registers such as `rbx`.

Thirdly, the routine as you have it will almost certainly crash, because the stack content on entry is *not* the same as on exit. You push `rax` at the end then attempt to return, meaning that the return address is almost certainly *not* what the CPU expects.

To that end, I would rewrite it as something like:

```
Times9:
    push rbx           ; save 

    push rax           ; rax -> rbx
    pop  rbx

    add  rax, rax      ; double
    add  rax, rax      ; quadruple
    add  rax, rax      ; octuple
    add  rax, rbx      ; now nine times

    pop  rbx           ; restore and return
    ret
```

Now, keep in mind that the multiply-by-eight operation can be done with shifting three bits left, something like:

```
    shl  rax, 3
```

but, then again, if brevity of code is your main concern, the entire multiply by nine can be done with `MUL` or `IMUL` so you may want to consider that.

Comment: Why did you use `push rax` and `pop rbx` to transfer RAX to RBX ? Why not the single instruction `mov rbx, rax` ? Any particular reason ?

Comment: @Fifoernik, I could wax lyrical about the likelihood that the stack is going to be in the L1 cache but, to be honest, it's more likely to be a hangover from my early days of programming 8080s and z80s where (from memory) it was smaller code, something that mattered on a 1K ZX80 where you had to *share* that 1K with the video memory :-) Even now, the `mov rbx, rax` encodes as `48 89 c3` while the `push/pop` is simply `50 5b` so you save a byte, not that it really matters that much nowadays.